# Joining two tiff images into one single page

Tags: macos, images, pictures, tiff

I would like to join two tif images into 1 image, 1 page. As far as I search online so far, there is only answers to how to join two tiff images into 1 file, containing 2 images, 2 pages.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you want exactly, but have you tried or considered at least, to do the desired by using Paint, that is cutting and pasting one to another and then resizing the paint's window for them both to fit?

Comment: paint in mac is not good enough....

Comment: What about installing paint.NET or GIMP?